# VueJs - Array of options with multi select checkbox and a textfield with value

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, sorting

Hello I'm trying to set the option value in a textfield when selected. The text input will only show when an option is selected and the value from the array user.roles should populate on input text as illustrated below but for some reason that won't work. Not sure why value can't simply show..

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: {
      email: 'test@test.com',
      roles: [{id: 1, name:'Client', value:'this is just a value'}]
    },
    roles: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Client',
        value:'',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Admin',
        value:'',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Guest',
        value:'',
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<template>

     <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="user.email" />
        </div>
        <div v-for="(role,index) in roles" :key="role.id">
            <label>{{role.name}}</label>
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="user.roles" :value="role"/>

            <p v-if="user.roles.includes(role)">
              
              <input type="text" value="The value from user.roles should go here.... instead of the value of role.value {{role.value}} /*** this does not work for some reason*/">
            </p>
        </div>

        <p>User's selected roels</p>
        {{user.roles}}
        </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you declare an empty string for the 'value' property in roles array,

**Edit**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: {
      email: 'test@test.com',
      roles: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Client',
        },
      ],
      rolesValue: ['Client Role Value']
    },
    roles: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Client',
        
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Admin',
        
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Guest',
        
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   getRoleIndex(id){
    return this.user.roles.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
   },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<template>

     <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="user.email" />
        </div>
        <div v-for="(role,index) in roles" :key="index">
            <label>{{role.name}}</label>
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="user.roles" :value="role"/>
            
            <p v-if="getRoleIndex(role.id) !== -1">
              <input type="text" v-model="user.rolesValue[getRoleIndex(role.id)]">
            </p>
        </div>

        <p>User's selected roels</p>
        {{user.roles}}
        <p>User's roles value</p>
        {{user.rolesValue}}
        </template>
</div>
```

Comment: what if I have a prefix value on roles[]? of course if i have something like roles[{id: 3,name: 'Guest', value:'Guest Role'}] that's going to work but what about if vlaue is not 'Guest Role' and it's something else? At that point your solution won't work and what i'm trying to do is have different values which can be preload and option should select and display value since roles[] has {id: 3,name: 'Guest', value:'whatever' Role'}

Comment: okay sorry, if you mean you want to show the user.roles.value in the textfield it should be like my edited answer

Comment: thank you very much this is what i wanted now how do we make the checkbox selected? if there is already a value in user.roles[{id: 1, name:'Client', value:'this is just a value'}]?

Comment: your welcome, to make auto checked, the user.roles.value and roles.value must be match, so just simply edit it, for example see my updated snippet!

Comment: ok I see what you did there but now your are using the same identical value from  roles[] which is wrong because remember we want to use the value from user.roles and not from roles[]. We also want to select and unselect the checkbox.

Comment: the problem is the index, so I fix it with `getRoleIndex(id)` method, maybe this is not a short way but it's what really you want

Comment: Raya again thanks man like if could pay you i would for all your help here. It seems that the updated code still doesn't work as expected. If I type something in the textfield the value doesn't update in user.roles(). Again let me give you a quick summary maybe i'm not being clear enough. The goal is if i choice a select, a textfield will show where i can enter a value and so far we have that. there will be instances where if i want to preload an option under user.roles then the checbok and value should be auto-select with value which isn't happening right now.

Comment: this is great what you did here user.roles[getRoleIndex(role.id)].value but why if i enter a new value doesn't reflect here  <p>User's selected roels</p>{{user.roles}} or on the textfield itself.

Comment: To binding it, just change the :value with v-model

Comment: Raya - That works like a perfectly!!!! one more thing, why does the checkbox unckeck when i start typing a new value?

Comment: and if i check it again, the user.roles[] get the object a second time. so duplicate it. i don't know why this is so hard

Comment: from your last summary above, we can solve it with changing the data structure, I split the user.roles.value property to outside roles array, maybe this is not the best practice but it works

Comment: ok that's good thanks again but if i uncheck the checkbox, the data remains in the user.roles intead of going away since i unchecked the checkbox. The idea is to store that in the database so that won't work because whatever was left in the value will be inserted into a table but that another topic. Never though this was so hard but i tried the following my self. instead of going through all the roles in roles[] i looped through all the roles in user.roles and then append whatever is roles are missing. let me know if you want to see the code.